# Typo3 Neos: How to use a flow plugin in a page template?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-flow, neoscms

If I have a flow plugin TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org:MyQuotesPlugin and I want to render the return value of the method 'quoteOfTheDayAction' which is implemented in my ActionController, how can I do that in my page template?

With Typo3 I would do it like this:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 < plugin.tx_myqoutesplugin_pi1
```

How can I do this with neos and fluid?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

In TypoScript:

```
page.body.content.quoteOfTheDay = TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org:MyQuotesPlugin {
    action = 'quoteOfTheDay'
}
```

then in your Body Template:

```
{content.quoteOfTheDay -> f:format.raw()}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian, that helps already!
but how can I tell typoscript which method of the action controller I want to call?
In my above example I want to call the method quoteOfTheDayAction of my MyQuotesPlugin.